# unwanted space on mobile views

Tags: html, css

I'm building an index page that contents consisted of only image carousel and fixed bottom navigation.

The problem comes on the mobile view which resulting **the unwanted white space** carousel image (image is responsive) and between the navigation.

So here's my nav code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg bg-dark fixed-bottom py-3" id="mainNav">
<div class="container">
  <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-dark navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto my-2 my-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="about.html">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="talent.html">Talent</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="schedule.html">Schedule</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here's my carousel code:

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/andira_hd.jpg" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/gofar_hd.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
  </div>
```

I have tried this, but it did not work.

@media (max-width: 576px) {
  body{overflow-x: hidden !important;}}

How do I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show some code and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: it's there, thank you for the advice.